# php variable in function name - wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to use a php variable to input the value as the shortcode name for wordpress.

Basically I have an option where people can create an options and give it a shortcode name.

Something like the following:

Is this possible?

```
$shortcode_name = "name_here";
function $shortcode_name ($atts) {
// code here
}
add_shortcode ($shortcode_name , $shortcode_name);
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004890/dynamic-function-name-in-php

Comment: @thebluefox not quite or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 5.3+ you have closures.

```
$shortcode_name = 'awesome';
${"{$shortcode_name}_fn"} = function($atts) {
  print('Awesome shortcode');
};
add_shortcode($shortcode_name, ${"{$shortcode_name}_fn"});
```

You can also have variable variable names, in this case, the variable that contains the function is named: awesome_fn.

Comment: Thanks for this. I get an error though - "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_fn' " - any ideas?

Comment: No problem. Hey check the updated answer, the variable variable name is now an interpolated string and the second argument for add_shortcode is the callable (a function in this case)

Comment: Yeah this works well :D The only thing is that I have this in a loop where for each id in the post type - to generate a shortcode with the options they give.

When I do this, it works perfectly for the first. I then add another and it overights the first. I dont think this is your code, but thought I would check?

Comment: Try using an asociative array of functions. Or maybe check no id is repeated

Comment: no idea what that is - but I think thats another answer - thanks for the help :D